# definable function

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a lenguage and $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\mathcal{L}$-structure.

prove that 
if $f: M^n \to M$ is definable then your image $f(M)$ is definable.

I know that if $f$ is definable then your graph  $\mathcal{G}_f \subset M^{n+1}$ is  definable, that is,  there is a formule $\varphi(x_1, \cdots , x_n, x_{n+1}) $ such that, $$ g_1, \cdots , g_n, g_{n+1} \in \mathcal{G}_f  \iff \mathcal{M} \models \varphi(g_1, \cdots , g_n, g_{n+1})   $$

but i don't know how to associate $\varphi$ with a formule that define to $f(M)$

Any help is important.

Thank your.

Answer (score 3):

$$ y\in \operatorname{image}(f)\iff\exists \vec x\in M^n:(\vec x,y)\in G_f\iff \mathcal M\models \exists \vec x\varphi(\vec x,y)$$